# CakePHP - Can you make forms submit params as named params?

Tags: cakephp, pagination, named-parameters

So GET forms make the usual urls like

```
.../search/?q=apple
```

Can you make a form create urls like

```
.../search/q:apple/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks, guys. I've found a different solution. I just submit the form as a POST and in the controller's action I read the post data and create a url with the post data as named params and then $this->redirect('...'); to it.

Answer (score 2):

The methods to create these URL's can be found here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/842/url

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you're not looking to create a different URI, per se, but rather to serialize the form data in a different way. In other words, you're interested in modifying the query string rather than the URI itself.

As far as I know, that's the way that forms serialize their data and there's no way to truly override this behavior. If you really want to do this, I suspect you'll have to capture the submit event, manually serialize the form data into the format you want, append that format to the form's `action` value, make a custom request to the page (via `location.href`, etc.) and return `false` so that the form itself never actually gets submitted.

Of course, you could also submit via Ajax where you have a little more control.

I'm not aware of any other way to do what I think you're asking.